# Why is my filmstrip not working in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm going to be stuck at my work all night unless I figure this out.

Do you have any idea why

```
    $('.filmstrip').mouseenter(function(){
        var isStopped = false;
        var $that = $(this),
               w = $that.width(),
              fr = $that.attr('data-framerate');
        $that.css('background-position-x',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart'));
        $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-gifurl')+')');
        for ( var i = 1, n = $that.attr('data-ticks'); i <= n && !isStopped; ++i )
        {
            (function(j){
               setTimeout(function(){
                  if (!isStopped) {
                      $that.css('background-position-x','-'+(w*j)+'px');
                  }
               }, j*fr);
            })(i);
        }
        $that.bind('mouseleave',function(){
            isStopped = true;
            $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position-x',$that.attr('data-placeholderXStart'));
        });
    });
```

is working on Chrome and IE but not Firefox? I'm put a `console.log` in there and the `mouseenter` event is not invoking. I've tried changing the event to `mouseover` and `hover` and still no luck.

Comment: Does it work when changing it to `click(function(){})`? Try using `bind` on `mouseover` just like you do on `mouseleave`.

Comment: what kind of element is filmstrip?